# Firebase authentication via email and password causing HttpClient.Timeout error in .NET Core 8

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, .net-8.0

I recently followed a tutorial by Milan Jovan on implementing Firebase authentication via email and password. However, upon implementing the solution provided in the tutorial, I encountered an unexpected error.

[Adding JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core With Firebase By Milan Javan](https://youtu.be/xBuLWaDcvu0?si=TRAh0mTaEBSnP4vO)

Here's the error message I get:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error!"
}
```

I've ensured that my implementation matches the steps outlined in the tutorial, yet the error persists. I've also verified my Firebase configuration and ensured that the necessary dependencies are correctly set up.

Code details - this is my method:

```
public async Task<string> RegisterUserWithEmailAsync(string? fullName, string? email, string? password)
{
     try
     {
         var userArgs = new UserRecordArgs()
         {
             //PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
             DisplayName = fullName,
             Disabled = false,
             EmailVerified = false,
             Email = email,
             Password = password,
         };

         var firebaseUserRecord = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync(userArgs);

         return firebaseUserRecord.Uid;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

This is my firebase connection configuration

```
private void ConnectFirebaseServiceAccount(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("private-key-file.json");
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = googleCredential
    });
}
```

Could someone please shed some light on what might be causing this issue? How can I resolve this `HttpClient.Timeout` error and successfully implement Firebase authentication via email and password?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!